# Performance MS SQL aggregate function Concatenate

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, aggregate-functions

Is there a way to make the following code perform faster then it is doing now? So the question really is: Is there a holy grail concatenate function with optimal performance or is this it?

We are using the concatenate function 4 or 5 times in a view and that is slowing the query down. We were wondering if we could make it faster so search results can be retrieved faster. It isn't slow now but faster would be better :-)

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Text;

[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined, MaxByteSize = 8000)]
public struct Concatenate : IBinarySerialize
{
  private StringBuilder value;

  public void Init()
  {
    value = new StringBuilder(500);
  }

  public void Accumulate(SqlString input)
  {
    if (input != null)
    {
      this.value.Append(", ");
      this.value.Append(input.Value);
    }
  }

  public void Merge(Concatenate input)
  {
    this.value.Append(", ");
    this.value.Append(input.value);
  }

  public SqlString Terminate()
  {
    if(value.Length > 2)
      value.Remove(0, 2);
    return new SqlString(value.ToString());
  }

  public void Read(BinaryReader r)
  {
    this.value = new StringBuilder(r.ReadString(), 500);
  }

  public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
  {
    w.Write(this.value.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the methods in this blog post: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Comment: @RichardDeeming that was a nice read. Thanks! We are still looking into this but we are probably going to flip everything around. Add an extra column and fill the record with the concatenated string. On every update we refresh the concatenated record. Then no concatenation will have to take place when we retrieve the rows. We are duplicating data but the speed is worth it.